# Java KeyEvent and KeyListener

Tags: java, keylistener, keyevent

Is the Java KeyListener universal meaning that it will work for any application that I type into?

If not, how can I make it universal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not universal. It only works if the component you registered it for has focus. You can use [keyboard hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1264/KeyBoard-Hooks) to make it universal, but you will either have to use [JNI](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jni.html) or [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna#readme) to integrate the native code.

Answer (score 1):

Please define "universal". Do you mean will it work as a key-logger? Answer: no. For that you'd need to write a key board hook that would be plugged into the operating system, something that can be done with Java via JNI or JNA, but something that Java is not well suited for.